# Odd CONCAT Error with Select/Insert

Tags: mysql, insert, concatenation

Any reason why this will return rows:

```
select users.user_fullname,concat(persons.first_name,' ',persons.last_name)
from users, persons
where users.user_id = persons.user_id
and users.user_fullname = '0'
```

Yet this throws a syntax error?

```
update users
set users.user_fullname = concat(persons.first_name,' ',persons.last_name)
from users, persons
where users.user_id = persons.user_id
and users.user_fullname = '0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `CONCAT`. The problem is that you should not have a `FROM` clause in an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) statement.

```
UPDATE users, persons
SET users.user_fullname = CONCAT(persons.first_name,' ',persons.last_name)
WHERE users.user_id = persons.user_id
AND users.user_fullname = '0'
```

Comment: Thank you! Coming from MSSQL I am still learning the syntactical differences...worked perfectly.